# Unable to build flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios-build

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unknown type name 'CGSize'; did you mean 'Size'?
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-AssetLibrary/PayUAssetLibraryKit.framework/Headers/PayUAssetLib
raryKit-Swift.h:267:22


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not build Objective-C module 'PayUAssetLibraryKit'
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-AssetLibrary/PayUAssetLibraryKit.framework/Modules/PayUAssetLib
raryKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:6:18


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Failed to build module 'PayUAssetLibraryKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2
(swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)'). Please select a toolchain which
matches the SDK.
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-CheckoutPro/PayUCheckoutProKit.framework/Modules/PayUCheckoutPr
oKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:6:7


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module '_StringProcessing'
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-PayUParams/PayUParamsKit.framework/Modules/PayUParamsKit.swiftm
odule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:9:7


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Failed to build module 'PayUParamsKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2
(swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)'). Please select a toolchain which
matches the SDK.
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-CheckoutProBase/PayUCheckoutProBaseKit.framework/Modules/PayUCh
eckoutProBaseKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:5:7


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Failed to build module 'PayUParamsKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2
(swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)'). Please select a toolchain which
matches the SDK.
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-NativeOtpAssist/PayUNativeOtpAssist.framework/Modules/PayUNativ
eOtpAssist.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:10:7


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Failed to build module 'PayUParamsKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2
(swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)'). Please select a toolchain which
matches the SDK.
/Users/apple/Documents/development/octoflutter/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/PayUIndia-UPICore/PayUUPICoreKit.framework/Modules/PayUUPICoreKit.swiftmo
dule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:10:7


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Failed to build module 'PayUCheckoutProKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.1
(swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)'). Please select a toolchain which
matches the SDK.
/Users/apple/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/payumoney_pro_unofficial-0.0.9/ios/Classes/SwiftPayumoneyProUnofficialPlugin.swift:2:7
```

Encountered error while building for device.

Getting this issue while flutter build ios and also from xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

You can either upgrade your Xcode which would come with a latest version of the swift compiler

or

You can download a higher version of swift compiler toolchain. Check out this post for this

https://medium.com/xcblog/switching-swift-versions-inside-xcode-using-toolchains-755b28831c43

Hope this helps